# Logic-grammar question

Tags: grammar, logic

Here is a logic-grammar question that I am struggling with.

Say I would like to say something like this:

[1] "If X did not happen, Y would be different."

The intended meaning of [1] is, of course:

[2] "If X did not happen, Y would be different from Y if X did happen."

Now, using [2] seems overly bulky to me and I am not even sure if it is grammatical.

[1] can be used with prior sentences providing context. Example:

> For many in the country, the lack of electricity is just another problem. And some cannot help but wonder whether the situation would be different if the military had not taken power.

In the above example, the first sentence (plus the prior ones that I have not included) provide context that help the second sentence seem correct.

The question is what to do when such context is absent. Example of [1] as a standalone sentence:

> The political leaning of a person would be different if he or she had no college degree.

In the above example there is no prior context. I am not sure if it is correct (in terms of logic and grammar) to use such a sentence. What I am trying to say here is: Each individual would have a certain leaning if he or she had a degree, and a different leaning if he or she had no degree.

My question is: Is it correct if I only use [1] instead of [2]? Alternatively, what is the right way to address these situations?

Comment: Did you do any research? For example, did you search the phrase "did not happen" with the phrase "would be different" to see how they're used together?

Comment: Yes, I did. [1] seems to be used when prior sentences help convey the meaning of the second part of [2]. The question is whether it would be possible to use [1] as a standalone sentence (i.e., without those prior sentences).

Comment: Then please include your research in the question (what you found, where you found it, why it didn't clear up the issue, etc.). Those are the kinds of things that make a good question on this site.

Comment: I could not find any grammarian source as this is a quite particular question. I resorted to newspaper articles. I ldid not store them but could try to retrieve new examples if this helps.

Comment: Yes, that would be useful. It would help to illustrate the issue, provide evidence that such structures are used in modern English, show that you are making an effort and not simply relying on others to do work for you, allow answerers to avoid repeating information that you clearly already know, etc.

Comment: Example: "For many in the country, the lack of electricity is just another problem. And some cannot help but wonder whether the situation would be different if the military had not taken power." >>> In this example, the first sentence (plus the prior ones that I have not included) provide context that help understand how Y would be different. The question is what to do when such context is absent.

Comment: Please [put all of that information in the question itself](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please). Comments may be deleted at any time, but those things should remain with the question.

Comment: @pierrot5 I've added your example to your question above. In future, you can do this yourself using the "Edit" button.

Comment: Thank you. I have edited the question with another example and some more comments.

Answer (score 2):

The sentence

> The political leaning of a person would be different if he or she had no college degree.

is grammatically valid, and a fluent speaker should have no trouble understanding it. It is not unnatural.

There is no rule or custom that requires a sentence of the form

> If X then Y would be different.

to have previous context. In some cases such context may be needed to make the meaning clear. Not in this case, at least not in my view.

---

By the way, when you assign an identifier to an example sentence, such as "[1]" or "(A), or "(2B)". it is helpful if you restrict that identifier to that **exact** sentence, and create a different identifier for related sentences you wish to discuss.

Comment: Thank you. Would you always use the short sentence instead of the longer, clearer, bulkier one?

Comment: @pierrot5 Probably Yes. At least, I cannot off-hand think of a situation where the longer one  would would seem preferable.

Comment: "X would be different if Y" seems to suggest that Y is not true—it is hypothetical. If you want to express a causal relationship between two things without treating one as real and the other as hypothetical, you can say "X depends on Y", "X differs/varies depending on Y", "for X, it matters whether Y", etc.

Comment: @nschneid The statement "X would be different if Y" does not imply that Y is either true or false. It can be, and often is, used for the exact same meaning as "X depends on Y". and similar statements.

Comment: I think it presents a hypothetical in the electricity example above. It may depend on context and the choice of "would" vs. "will".